# With SQL how can I get the columns that recur more more than twice?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the SQL request I tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT um.user_id)
FROM wp_usermeta um
LEFT JOIN wp_users u ON um.user_id = u.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_posts p ON u.ID = p.post_author AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_type = 'post'
WHERE p.post_date >= '2013-03-15'
AND u.user_login NOT LIKE 'LOCKED-%'
AND um.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
AND um.meta_value LIKE '%writers%'
AND COUNT(um.user_id) >= 2
```

The last line:

```
AND COUNT(um.user_id) >= 2
```

Is causing some errors.

Is there a way to only get the um.user_id that recur at least twice or more?

Comment: basic rule: you cannot use aggregate functions in `where` clauses. the `where` filtering is done at the time each row is being filtered for inclusion into the result set. the aggregate results canNOT be available until ALL rows have been determined, so you're essentially asking the DB to time travel. There's why there's `having` clauses, which apply their filters at the end of the query chain, when all aggregate results have been computed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group by the users and use the `having` clause to apply aggregate functions like `count` on each group

```
select count(*) from
(
    SELECT um.user_id
    FROM wp_usermeta um
    LEFT JOIN wp_users u ON um.user_id = u.ID
    LEFT JOIN wp_posts p ON u.ID = p.post_author AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_type = 'post'
    WHERE p.post_date >= '2013-03-15'
    AND u.user_login NOT LIKE 'LOCKED-%'
    AND um.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
    AND um.meta_value LIKE '%affiliate_pay_per_publish%'
    GROUP BY um.user_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
) alias_name
```

Comment: I want to know the number of users thats why I had put COUNT(DISTINCT um.user_id) after the select.

Comment: Then put a `select count` around it

Comment: `alias_name` ? I thought it was just `A` -- I guess they're the same? Also, i think two queries are often faster than a subqueries.

Comment: @JackWilliams: You need to give every subquery a name. I chose `alias_name` but `a` would be fine too.